# High cpu load with picturebox refresh (25 fps)

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming, picturebox

I try to display a live stream from a network camera in a picturebox, i receive every 40ms a new image i cannot determine which area are of the picture are changed so `pictureBox1.Invalidate(targetRect)` not work for me. It works fine but the CPU usage is high.

Is an other good control available in winform that is more suitable for this task? I need a control with a image update method.

**Winform - refresh logic**

```
private void ReceiveFrame(byte[] imageData)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref this._fps);
    var lastImage = this.pictureBox1.Image;

    var image = this.ByteToImage(imageData);
    if (this.pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.pictureBox1.Image = image; });
    }
    else
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }

    lastImage?.Dispose();
}

private Image ByteToImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            return Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**WPF - refresh logic (update my question - part1)**
The CPU usage is also high

```
private void ReceiveFrame(byte[] image)
{
    this.LiveImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { this.LiveImage.Source = this.ByteToBitmapFrame(image); }));
}

private BitmapFrame ByteToBitmapFrame(byte[] imageData)
{
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Write(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            return BitmapFrame.Create(memoryStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Winform - refresh logic (update my question - part2)**

The ByteToImage method need 6ms per Image (Resolution:1920x1080, Size:6MB, Format:BMP) i have optimize the speed with set validateImageData to false, now it need 3,5ms per Image. First i have a Problem with a GDI exception, the problem occurs if the MemoryStream dispose if you need the Image in a picturebox dont use it with an using. [Image Draw Performance msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/omars/2004/03/29/system-drawing-image-performance/)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| Resolution | Format | Size  | ValidateImageData | Duration  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1920x1080  | BMP    | 6MB   | true              | 6ms       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1920x1080  | BMP    | 6MB   | false             | 3.5ms     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1920x1080  | JPEG   | 270KB | true              | 10ms      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1920x1080  | JPEG   | 270KB | false             | 0.1ms     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Example ValidateImageData**

```
private static Image ByteToImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    try
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData.Length))
        {
            memoryStream.Write(imageData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            return Image.FromStream(memoryStream, false, false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: WinForms uses CPU for rendering, WPF uses the GPU. I'd suggest you to use WPF when you care about graphics performance

Comment: You could always use VLC ActiveX plugin or some other third party plugin to display webcam streams. They do the work for you and don't consume CPU that often.

Comment: @SurajS I cannot found a method in the `VlcControl` to set Images i dont have a videofile i have only the Images available.

Comment: @TomBaires The Camera should provide you a stream-able link.You can set that url as the video source there is no need to set images and you cant. axVlc is an ActiveX plugin

Comment: @TomBaires This link should point you in a good direction https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/8c6f12d1-bcb5-4aca-9ed2-063e9cbb7cb4/connect-with-ip-camera?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: @SurajS i have a Server-Client application and the Server receives the stream and decode it, the client receives the Frames from the Server application.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i have try with WPF but the performance is the same

Comment: @TomBaires I just tried an app that refreshes an Image every 2 ms and it has 0% on my CPU. Are you constantly checking on a background thread for instance?!!!!

Comment: Try the Windows Media Player SDK or for more flexibility checkout DirectShow